# VSCode Emmet tab through

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am using VSCode to write HTML and using emmets. When ever there are more lines/elements, one line/element is getting skipped. Please see the picture in the link.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: Yup, reported and getting fixed in next release. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Reported & getting fixed in the next insider release.

Ref: [Github Emmet Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42980)